# Why Elastic MapReduce job flow failed in AWS MapReduce?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-iam

I created a job flow in AWS MapReduce, I created a job flow of Contextual Advertising (Hive Script) - done 'Start interactive Hive Session', selected m1.small instances, proceeded without a VPC subnet id and Configure Hadoop in Configure Bootstrap actions.
Now, job flow goes into starting state and after 15-20 minutes it goes into failed state and it does not go into waiting state. 
It shows "Last State Change Reason: User account is not authorized to call EC2 " 
I gave PowerUserAccess to myself thru IAM. also I have given below policies to myself.

1.AmazonEC2FullAccess
2.AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess
3.IAMFullAccess

After giving all these policies still it shows "User account is not authorized to call EC2"

please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EMR builds on other AWS services that you also need to subscribe to.  Giving IAM privileges to  call ec2, s3 and emr is not sufficient.